# how does huber compute the $var(s_n)/E[s_n]$ and $var(d_n)/E[d_n]$?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance, functional-calculus, robust-statistics

How does Huber in book 'Robust statistical procedures' in chapter 1 compute the variance of certain statistical functions?
He defines the mean square deviation to be $$s_n = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum \left(x_i - \bar{x} \right)^2}$$
and the mean absolute deviation as $$d_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum \| x_i - \bar{x} \|.$$
Then he goes on to obtain the asymptotic relative efficiency expression ARE($\epsilon$) as shown in the photo. (So, we should have at least for arguments in the ARE(), namely,
ARE($\epsilon;n,x_i,x$),right? even if $n \to \infty.$ What does ARE() look like before we send $n \to \infty$?
How on earth does one obtain the expression in the 2nd step?)

What is $var(s_n), E[s_n]$? How to obtain these expressions?

Finally, why does he state that just two bad observations in 1000 suffice to offset the 12% advantage of the mean square error? Is is not 5 bad observations? See [image: Table 1] in the photo, values for $\epsilon = 0.005$ is 1.198 which is the (12%) I guess?