# how does Huber compute the $var(s_n)/E[s_n]$ and $var(d_n)/E[d_n]$?

Tags: probability-theory

I cross posted on [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772929/how-does-huber-compute-the-vars-n-es-n-and-vard-n-ed-n) at  the following question because of lack
of response. Perhaps this question was too advanced for math stackexchange,
or perhaps I was asking too many things at the same time,
but I still wish for an elementary, step by step response.
Please forgive me for cross-posting.

===

How does Huber in book 'Robust statistical procedures' in chapter 1 compute the variance of certain statistical functions?
He defines the mean square deviation to be $$s_n = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum \left(x_i - \bar{x} \right)^2}$$
and the mean absolute deviation as $$d_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum \| x_i - \bar{x} \|.$$
Then he goes on to obtain the asymptotic relative efficiency expression ARE($\epsilon$) as shown in the photo. (So, we should have at least for arguments in the ARE(), namely,
ARE($\epsilon;n,x_i,x$),right? even if $n \to \infty.$ What does ARE() look like before we send $n \to \infty$?
How on earth does one obtain the expression in the 2nd step?)

What is $var(s_n), E[s_n]$? How to obtain these expressions?

Finally, why does he state that just two bad observations in 1000 suffice to offset the 12% advantage of the mean square error? Is is not 5 bad observations? See [![Table 1][1]][1] in the photo, values for $\epsilon = 0.005$ is 1.198 which is the (12%) I guess?

Comment: Hi Peter, and welcome to the MathOverflow. Cross posted is not prohibited, but you should await at least a few days (ideally a week) before doing it, in order to allow for the site member to arrange a meaningful answer: 20 hours are definitively too much less.